# With Java Spring is there an advantage to use @Transactional attribute for a single statement

Tags: java, spring, transactions

If my method does a get and then update, is it a good practice to add the @Transactional attribute to the method as the database engine (PostgreSQL) will treat the update as an implicit transaction ? Any overhead of adding the transactional attribute ? I am already using OptimisticLockType.ALL to avoid losing data between the read & update.

Comment: Adding `@Transactional` at the method level will, AFAIK, cause all code inside that method to execute within a single logical transaction.  This would make sense if, for example, you wanted your get and update upsert logic to behave atomically.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As I understand, with the OptimisticLockType.ALL , the update would fail if the row was updated between the get & update. Is there any advantage of adding the transaction attribute in this case ?

Comment: Not sure...but maybe `@Transactional` would prevent that other process/thread from even being able to do an update.